# SimpleXML: How do I get other attributes when selecting nodes that contain a namespaced attribute?

Tags: php, xpath, svg, simplexml, xml-namespaces

How do I get other attributes when selecting nodes that contain a namespaced attribute?

I have an SVG with `xlink:href`, and I am trying to access the `id` attribute, but when using xpath it seems to only return an "attribute node". How do I get the actual "element node"?

```
$xml = new \SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <image id="my-image" xlink:href="http://example.com/image.png" />
    </svg>
');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('svg', 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg');
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('xlink', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink');
$images = $xml->xpath('//svg:image/@xlink:href');
foreach ($images as $image) {
    var_dump($image);
}
```

Output:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#2 (1) {
  ["@attributes"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["href"]=>
    string(28) "http://example.com/image.png"
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/lvILL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The correct xpath is:

```
$images = $xml->xpath('//svg:image[@xlink:href]');
```

https://3v4l.org/NTcvP